# mysql string to date

Tags: mysql, date-format

I got error when i try to change string to date.

```
mysql> select STR_TO_DATE('03.05.2010 00:00','%d.%m.%Y %h:%i');
+--------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('03.05.2010 00:00','%d.%m.%Y %h:%i') |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                             |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0,00 sec)
```

how can i convert to date from `'03.05.2010 00:00'` ? Thanks

Comment: min and seconds are always 00:00?

Comment: just to add for answer - %h it from 01 to 12, %H - 00-23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use %H instead of %h.

```
select STR_TO_DATE('03.05.2010 00:00','%d.%m.%Y %H:%i');
```

Or, if HH:MM are always 00:00 you can use date part only:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('03.05.2010 00:00','%d.%m.%Y');
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/CCPKR29919

As @a_vlad has pointed out on his comments, %H is used to format hours as 00..23 and %h as 01..12.

Have a look at [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) on MySql docs.